# Kibana data suddenly got missing

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Today morning when I've tried to open my Kibana, I found the following error in my browser.

[click to see the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ksew.png)

Then I've restarted Kibana. But after the restart, all of my indexes have been lost.

[click to see the attached image refer to the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8oiK.png)

After that, to view all my works such that dashboards, visuals, I've imported my Saved Object backup file that is in json format.
After imported, I found all the visuals and dashboards are there as it is but I've lost past data from elasticsearch. I found data only from yesterday's 00:00 hour to the current date-time.

Why this type of sudden data loss has happened?
Can I somehow track the incident from a log or somewhere?
I've read a few posts in the elastic blog that refer to the same kind of issue.
Is that that a security threat?
Please help guys!!

Comment: please attach image inline

Comment: Are you using docker for your Elastic stack? Did you check Kibana/Elasticsearch logs for the cause?

Comment: No, I'm not using docker. Can you please let me know how to check Kibana/Elasticsearch logs? as I'm new to Kibana. Please help!